# Logging into phpMyAdmin error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, macos-sierra

I access the phpMyAdmin login page by 127.0.0.1/~username/phpmyadmin.

When I try to go to 127.0.0.1/~username/phpmyadmin/setup I get the following error:

phpMyAdmin - Error
Configuration already exists, setup is disabled!

I am trying to setup phpmyadmin with mysql which I downloaded and have spent the last 2 days trying every solution I've found on here.

At one point I was able to access 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/setup and created a server with my mysql password but now I can't even access this

Below is my config.inc.php code:

```
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */

/**
 * phpMyAdmin sample configuration, you can use it as base for
 * manual configuration. For easier setup you can use setup/
 *
 * All directives are explained in documentation in the doc/ folder
 * or at <https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/>.
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */

/**
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie. Needs to be 32 chars long.
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ''; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/**
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/**
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

/**
 * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
 */

/* User used to manipulate with storage */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = '';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlport'] = '';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass';

/* Storage database and tables */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';

/**
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/**
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

/**
 * Whether to display icons or text or both icons and text in table row
 * action segment. Value can be either of 'icons', 'text' or 'both'.
 * default = 'both'
 */
//$cfg['RowActionType'] = 'icons';

/**
 * Defines whether a user should be displayed a "show all (records)"
 * button in browse mode or not.
 * default = false
 */
//$cfg['ShowAll'] = true;

/**
 * Number of rows displayed when browsing a result set. If the result
 * set contains more rows, "Previous" and "Next".
 * Possible values: 25, 50, 100, 250, 500
 * default = 25
 */
//$cfg['MaxRows'] = 50;

/**
 * Disallow editing of binary fields
 * valid values are:
 *   false    allow editing
 *   'blob'   allow editing except for BLOB fields
 *   'noblob' disallow editing except for BLOB fields
 *   'all'    disallow editing
 * default = 'blob'
 */
//$cfg['ProtectBinary'] = false;

/**
 * Default language to use, if not browser-defined or user-defined
 * (you find all languages in the locale folder)
 * uncomment the desired line:
 * default = 'en'
 */
//$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
//$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'de';

/**
 * How many columns should be used for table display of a database?
 * (a value larger than 1 results in some information being hidden)
 * default = 1
 */
//$cfg['PropertiesNumColumns'] = 2;

/**
 * Set to true if you want DB-based query history.If false, this utilizes
 * JS-routines to display query history (lost by window close)
 *
 * This requires configuration storage enabled, see above.
 * default = false
 */
//$cfg['QueryHistoryDB'] = true;

/**
 * When using DB-based query history, how many entries should be kept?
 * default = 25
 */
//$cfg['QueryHistoryMax'] = 100;

/**
 * Whether or not to query the user before sending the error report to
 * the phpMyAdmin team when a JavaScript error occurs
 *
 * Available options
 * ('ask' | 'always' | 'never')
 * default = 'ask'
 */
//$cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'always';
```

I'm guessing something is wrong here but my mind is melting looking at all of this for so long.

Any ideas on what my issue is?

Thanks
I am running macOS Sierra if that helps anything

Also when I try to login to my mysql I get these errors:

## 2002 - No such file or directory — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

Comment: Are you sure mysql is running?

Comment: Yes when I go into system preferences and click mySQL it says server instance is running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some initial research, I believe I have a solution for you.

I would try changing:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

To:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

[My Source](http://blog.ryantremaine.com/2011/03/2002-cannot-log-in-to-mysql-server.html)

Comment: I ended up having to reset my mysql password too, but I also needed to do this,thanks!

Comment: Ok. SO *REALLY* needs to clear out all these obsolete answers referring to settings that don't exist anymore. It's impossible to find a solution when there are hundreds of invalid answers in google's search results.

Answer (score 2):

> phpMyAdmin - Error Configuration already exists, setup is disabled!

This means you already have a `config.inc.php` in the root phpMyAdmin directory, so the setup script won't run as a security precaution. You can move or rename `config.inc.php` in order to work with the setup script.

> 2002 - No such file or directory — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

This either means the MySQL daemon isn't running at all, or that the socket path you've pointed phpMyAdmin to isn't the socket used by MySQL. The way I suggest troubleshooting this is to use the command-line client to connect (`mysql -u root -p` or use a different username if 'root' isn't appropriate here). If you can connect, run the `STATUS;` command to see connection information, including socket path (if the connection is via socket; if it's via tcp/ip networking you'll see that and port 3306 instead of a socket path).

Note that you've set the host to 'localhost' which has special meaning to MySQL and basically overrides the connect_type definition. With 'localhost', you're using sockets and in many cases on Mac systems, for some reason the default paths used by MySQL and PHP don't match. The ideal solution is to edit your PHP configuration file to define the proper path to the socket, but phpMyAdmin also has the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']` directive for you to specific the path to the socket. If you wish/need to use the TCP/IP protocol instead, use the hostname 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Nope. I removed the config.inc.php file completely, searched my hard drive to make sure it was going. Still getting this same error.